# FactoryGirl Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Not quite sure how to set up the association in FactoryGirl, or if what I am doing is really an association.

In `users.rb` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    id 12345
    email joe@example.com

  factory :admin do
    id 67890
    email admin@example.com
  end
end
```

Group has the property of `email`.

In `groups.rb` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group do
    association :admin.email, factory: admin
    id 123
  end
```

So, what I am trying to do is use the admin's email as the email property for the instance of a Group. Essentially I want `association :admin.email, factory: admin` to evaluate to `admin@example.com`.

Is this an association? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It's not an association.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group do
    email { admin.email }
    id 123
  end
```